# Access knockout bound value directly from target element in event handler

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am struggling a bit with implementing a custom tooltip binding that is invoked with a mouseover, so I need an event handler to display the tooltip. Now, the content of the tooltip can be *either* a static string, *or* an observable with content that can change - but the tooltip module itself is a singleton. Plus, there can be more than one tooltip elements on the page, so the tooltip `show` function just receives the event and the content to display. For me, the easiest way would be if I could access the *actual bound value* from the event target in the listener alone.

Now I know there is the `ko.dataFrom` function, but for the static variant, I cannot see the actual bound value anywhere (i.e. the same that is returned with `valueAccessor()` in the init function), just the whole viewmodel.

Here is some simplified code to illustrate it:

```
<span class="icon help" data-bind="tooltip: 'some static string'"></span>
```

(But as I said there also might be an observable behind the tooltip binding)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tooltip = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        element.addEventListener("mouseover", ko.bindingHandlers.tooltip.showTooltip);
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            element.removeEventListener("mouseover", ko.bindingHandlers.tooltip.showTooltip);
        });
    },
    showTooltip: function(event) {
        var data = ko.dataFor(this);
        tooltip.show(event, data);
    }
}
```

The problem is now that "data" only contains the whole viewmodel the view was bound to. But where is 'some static string' to be found?

I also tried with "ko.contextFor", but then $root, $data and $rawData were all the same. I am sure I overlooked something here, or is that not possible without adding the string to a data attribute or something similar, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental issue here is that you shouldn't be trying to reuse the event handler, or at least, if you're going to, bind it.

I'd just move `showTooltip` into `init`:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tooltip = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var showTooltip = function(event) {
            tooltip.show(event, ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
        };
        element.addEventListener("mouseover", showTooltip);
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            element.removeEventListener("mouseover", showTooltip);
        });
    }
};
```

Small functions are *very cheap*.

**Live Example** (using `click` instead of `mouseover` and just appending to the document):

```js
var tooltip = {
  show: function(event, value) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = "tooltip: " + value;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
};
ko.bindingHandlers.tooltip = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var showTooltip = function(event) {
            tooltip.show(event, ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
        };
        element.addEventListener("click", showTooltip);
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            element.removeEventListener("click", showTooltip);
        });
    }
};

var vm = {
  items: [
    {text: "one", tooltip: "uno"},
    {text: "two", tooltip: "due"},
    {text: "three", tooltip: "tre"},
    {text: "four", tooltip: "quattro"}
  ]
};
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.body);
// To prove the observables work, update one after a delay
setTimeout(function() {
  vm.items[2].tooltip = "TRE";
}, 100);
```

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
  <div data-bind="text: text, tooltip: tooltip"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Alternately, use `bind`:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tooltip = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var boundHandler = ko.bindingHandlers.tooltip.showTooltip.bind(
            null,
            valueAccessor
        );
        element.addEventListener("click", boundHandler);
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            element.removeEventListener("click", boundHandler);
        });
    },
    showTooltip: function(valueAccessor, event) {
        tooltip.show(event, ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
    }
};
```

```js
var tooltip = {
  show: function(event, value) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = "tooltip: " + value;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
};
ko.bindingHandlers.tooltip = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var boundHandler = ko.bindingHandlers.tooltip.showTooltip.bind(
            null,
            valueAccessor
        );
        element.addEventListener("click", boundHandler);
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            element.removeEventListener("click", boundHandler);
        });
    },
    showTooltip: function(valueAccessor, event) {
        tooltip.show(event, ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
    }
};

var vm = {
  items: [
    {text: "one", tooltip: "uno"},
    {text: "two", tooltip: "due"},
    {text: "three", tooltip: "tre"},
    {text: "four", tooltip: "quattro"}
  ]
};
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.body);
// To prove the observables work, update one after a delay
setTimeout(function() {
  vm.items[2].tooltip = "TRE";
}, 100);
```

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
  <div data-bind="text: text, tooltip: tooltip"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Note how the bound value will be in front of the event argument.

Comment: Thank you! That worked, both with dynamic as well as with static values. Questions: why would you suggest to not reuse the event handler, I cannot see any negative side effects with doing this? And why did you use the actual `show` function outside of `init` in your 1st code snippet? Also seems to work if you directly call `tooltip.show' from within like in your topmost code sample.

Comment: @frontend_dev: The main reason for putting it inside is so you take advantage of it being a closure over `valueAccessor`, which does away with the need for figuring out what that is later. I'm afraid I don't quite understand your `show` question.

Comment: I asked because your snippet differs from your first code example. In the snippet you added `var tooltip = { show: ... ` but that seems not necessary.

Comment: @frontend_dev: That's just a shim for the `tooltip` object you're using in your code (which is why it's in the snippet, but not in the code block). It's in your `showTooltip` function in the question.

Comment: OK, understand. Yes "in reality" this is a completely separate module. Thanks for helping me out!